# Sort Data in Excel in a Sequence

Tags: excel, sorting

Is it possible in Excel file to sort the data in a sequence?

I am trying to sort my data with the following details for example:

```
Column A
A
A
B
B
```

The output should be like this:

```
Column A
A
B
A
B
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I don't think it is possible to sort based on a pattern like you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs @GharbadTheWeak, I'll seek another method to sort my data in excel. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you may perhaps try, is to have a column B added  and put number behind from 1 to 2 so A and 1 A and 2, then B and 1 and B and 2 and sort afterwards by column B ... Don’t know, if this is solving your problem ...

Comment: Putting `=countif($A$1:$A2,A2)` in cell B2 will do this